# slight delay onsubmit javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

hello I have a chat system which works ok but when user click submit the message does not show instantly on the senders side there is a slight delay. Sometimes it appears on the receivers side before the senders side. any help on improving this situation.

```
      <script>

    function submitChat(){

        if ( form1.msg.value == ''){

            alert('enter your message');
            return false;

        }

            $('#imageload').show();
            var msg = form1.msg.value;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
               // var Data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                 document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML;

                    $('#imageload').hide();


                }


            }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?&msg='+msg, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                    document.forms['form1'].reset();

            }


        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#chatlogs").load('reg.php', function(){
        $("#chatlogs").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chatlogs")[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
                  window.setInterval(function() { var elem = document.getElementById('chatlogs'); elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight; }, 340);
            });
        });



        $(document).ready(function(e){

        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function(){$('#chatlogs').load('reg.php')}, 2000);

        });

        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(".chatbox:focus") && (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false)  ) {
            submitChat();
            e.preventDefault();
            }
         });

    </script>
```

Comment: This question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Todo that, you have to append the text directly to the page, with innerHTML, without waiting for the answer from the server with Ajax call. Because the processing on the server side always takes time, so is the answer. Then when you get the answer you replace the appended text by the ajax answer.

Comment: not sure I understand, could you give me an example please.

Comment: What I mean is, just after var msg = form1.msg.value; before sending the message to the server, you can put the value directly in your target HTML element, and then once you get the answer, inside the block xmlhttp.status == 200, you replace the sent message by the answer, to avoid duplicated message in the chat board, because in this case you just want to display the sent message in the sender side.